# How to switch between the roles Symfony 6?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to switch between roles in Symfony that depend on `onAuthenticationSuccess`

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
{
    if ($targetPath = $this-\>getTargetPath($request-\>getSession(), $firewallName)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
    }

    $user = $token->getUser();

    if (in_array("ROLE_INSTRUCTOR", $user->getRoles(), true)) {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_instructor'));
    }
}

protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
{
    return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?